# C#/XAML: Get Textbox value from DataTemplate Textbox in DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, xaml, textbox, datatemplate

**The sitatuion:**

I've a DataGridView on my WPF Application that is connected to my SQL server.
I created a Textbox, which doesn't really exist, inside a DataTemplate.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Amount">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBox x:Name="txtAmount"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

This ensures that every column has a Textbox. Now I want to get the Textbox value from the currentcell or the last cell where some value is put in (on the DataGridView) and I want use this value to insert the value in another column of the database table. 
I have approached many sources but unfortunately I don't know how to implement this inside my program. I tried something with Binding, but that didn't work out.

I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: use binding,MVVM framework with Xaml

Comment: Did any of the solution help you? If no, update your question providing more details. In other case mark the answer you were looking for/ was useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the data context for your DataGrid,  datagrid's row inherits that ( row's data context is a single element from the collection that you are binding your DataGrid to).

If you want to bind to some value outside DataGrid, that's a tricky case, because the column doesn’t belong to the visual or logical tree of the DataGrid. You have to use some kind of [proxy](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful.

Comment: @ICTFreak No problem, you can vote up my answer  if you want to:)

Answer (score 0):

Make use of Textbox.TextChanged event. If you are using MVVM, bind a method with converter to obtain data from the cell that has changed..
Use this value to apply on any other column.

You can make use of converterparameter to bind in the cell where you will need to make changes...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful.